# Visual basic / how to take a word in a text box and output a numerical value

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning visual basic in college right now, and i find it really confusing. How do I take the input of a text box as as string and write out a procedure for a button that takes the input and outputs a variable in the list box. For example i want to assign various values to strings such as the price of a chair = $10 and price of table = $40 . How do would you write it so that when you click the button it takes the word chair in the text boxs and outputs a value in the list box.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this I'm not sure where to start.  For example, to determine how to store the item/price pairs, we have to know what you've studied so far?  Collection classes?  Databases?  Files?  XML?  Also, please clarify if this is VB.NET or VB6.  (I realize it's likely VB.NET, but you never know.)  This might also be too big an answer for this forum.  It sounds like it's worth a chapter in a textbook just to cover it. You might be better served going here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx  The lessons are geared toward beginners and might be easier.

Comment: Forget the link in my previous comment - - start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466159

Comment: @David Stratton - He never mentioned .NET. It could be possible that he's learning something like VB6 or VBA... Are you doing VB.NET Braeden?

Comment: Im using visual basic express 2010, with no prior knowledge of visual basic.

Comment: its easy to declare the string chair as a double and then use lstBox.Items.Add(chair) and have it display the correct number. But what i don't know how to do is  adding values to the listbox using the output of what ever is input into the textbox. When i type in chair how can i get it to convert the string chair to the value i specified. instead of just printing the word chair in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetPrice(ByVal key As String) As Decimal
    Dim priceTable As New Dictionary(Of string, Decimal)()
    priceTable.Add("chair", 10.0)
    priceTable.Add("table", 40.0)

    Return If(priceTable.ContainsKey(key), priceTable(key), 0)
End Function

Public Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(GetPrice(Textbox1.Text).ToString())
End Sub
```